# .htaccess SEO URL Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want:

```
website.com/category.php?name=discussion
```

to turn into:

```
website.com/forums/discussion
```

This is my code but it doesn't appear to work. mod_rewrite is enabled and htaccess files are allowed in the Apache configuration. Can anyone help?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)$ /category.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Additionally, I tried the following code, and it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule forums/category/(.*) /category.php?name=$1 [L]
```

But it produces the following url: website.com/forums/category/discussion which is not what I want.

Please don't mark this as duplicate, I've checked all of the other links regarding url rewrites and used all of the rewrite codes but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn

`website.com/category.php?name=discussion`
into:
`website.com/forums/discussion`

You need to use 2 different rules one for redirecting `/category.php?name=foobar` to `/forums/foobar` and the other to map the new url to the old one.

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect the old url to the new location 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /category.php\?name=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /forums/%1? [L,R]
# map the new url to the old location
RewriteRule ^forums/(.*)/?$ /category.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tied it but it did not work. Is there supposed to be a space after ^ and /forums in RewriteRule ^ /forums/%1? [L,R]? I tried it without the space and it did not work either.

Comment: @hmzfier `^` in the rule above is pattern of RewriteRule while the `/forums/%1?` is destination path of the rule. So yes a space is there to separate the arguments.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  What happens when you type `website.com/category.php?name=val` ?

Comment: It ended up being another rewrite rule conflicting with this one. Thanks for the help, your code works!